# Copy selection from one select field to many other select fields with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select, copy, selection, field

I have a select in a form with a button next to it. Below is an unknown quantity of other select fields.

```
<select class="offer_1 value_source" name="xnamex">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="xxxxxxx">Text</option>
</select>
<button class="copy_select offer_1" type="button" name="Copy" value="">Copy Down</button>
<select class="offer_1" name="xnamex">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="xxxxxxx">Text</option>
</select>
<!-- unknown quantity of selects follow -->
```

I am grouping the select fields and button together via the class offer_{number}

I want to copy the selected value from the one select with the class value_source to all other selects with the same class (offer_{number}).

Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.copy_select').click(function() {
        attr_class = $(this).attr('class');
        attr_class = attr_class.replace('copy_select ', '.');
        $(attr_class).val($(attr_class + ' value_source').val());
        alert(attr_class);
    });
});
```

All selects remain unselected and my copy_source get reset to unselected.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, how would I check that the select has a value set and throw up an `alert()` if not?

Many, many thanks for your time :)

Comment: This might make your life a hell of a lot easier: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: @Inerdial by having the work already done/tested for controlling the selects?

Comment: @DanHeberden What work? You can control selects just fine without it.

Comment: @inerdial - you're right, why even use jQuery?

Comment: @DanHeberden You haven't shown how the library you suggest is of any use whatsoever in solving the OP's problem or how it would make any of the answers below easier to implement or understand. I don't see what jQuery has to do with it.

Comment: @Inerdial - it looked like the OP's process/whatever might make use of hiding/showing selects instead of copying data, so i just mentioned the plugin incase that was something the OP was after - it's not like i made an answer about it, just a comment in efforts to corral possible needs of the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's wrong with your original example, this does what I think you want to do. That is, when the button is clicked, select the current value from `select.offer_1.value_source` in *all* other selects with the class `offer_1`; and not to selects with the class `offer_2` which will be handled with another button.

#### JavaScript

```
$('.copy_select').click(function() {
    $selects = $($(this).data('selects'));
    $source = $selects.filter('.value_source');
    $copies = $selects.not('.value_source');
    console.log($selects);
    console.log($source);
    console.log($copies);
    console.log($source.val());
    $copies.val($source.val());
})
```

#### HTML

```
<select class="offer_1 value_source" name="xnamex">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="a">Text</option>
    <option value="b">Foo</option>
    <option value="c">Bar</option>
</select>
<button class="copy_select" data-selects='.offer_1' type="button" name="Copy" value="">Copy Down</button>
<select class="offer_1" name="xnamex">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="a">Text</option>
    <option value="b">Foo</option>
    <option value="c">Bar</option>
</select>
```

(I'm using a data attribute on the `<button>` to associate the button with the `<select>`s because data attributes are awesome and parsing CSS class strings isn't.)

[Obligatory jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MeNZr/5/).

Comment: Awesome! This answer works. I was hesitant to use it because of the data attribute (this is still an xHTML site).

Comment: @atwright You can always just replace that one line with code that inspects the classes of the element for a pattern. But given the choice of XHTML compliance and clearer code I went with the latter for an SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood the question correctly, and assuming your HTML always follows that layout, I would suggest something like this:

```
$(".copy_select").click(function() {
    $("select[class^='offer_']").val($(this).prev().val());
});
```

Note that the use of [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) means the `select` element will always have to directly precede the `button` element. I've used an "[attribute starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector to select `select` elements with a class beginning with "offer_".

Comment: +1 you're close, but I understand he wants to copy the selected option to all other "offer_" selects...

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. This will work if the selected option is present in all the other `offer_` select elements too.

Comment: This works perfectly! Many thanks to James Allardice and EVERYONE ELSE who offered solutions -- you are all legends :)

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. If someone selects an option with an empty value attribute and clicks the button, EVERY select input gets reset to that empty option.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".copy_select").click(function() {
    // store value
    var v =  $( ".value_source option:selected" ).val();
    // store text
    var t =  $( ".value_source option:selected" ).text();
    $("select[class^='offer_']").append(
         "<option value=\"" + v + "\">" + t + "</option>"
    );
  });
});
```